# How to force wget to convert *all* downloaded links to relative ones?

Tags: wget

For having an offline version of Oracles Java tutorials¹, where all links to the Java API shall point to the also downloaded local version of the Java API docs, I use the following wget command (look out if trying: gets over 25,000 files):

```
wget -mkp -nH -nv -E  --accept-regex ".*javase/8/docs/api.*|.*javase/tutorial.*" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/
```

Unfortunately only a part of the links are converted to point correctly to the local files. All files under `javase/tutorial` are fine, but all the files pointing from there to the API files which are downloaded to `javase/8/docs/api` do not point to this local files, but instead point still to the online version.

Any ideas what's wrong?

––––

¹ I know there is a downloadable version of the tutorials, but it's API links point only to the online Java API doc.

Comment: Using `curl` would be also OK?

Comment: Can you give the path to a file that did not convert the links? Running your command here _seems_ to have converted the links in the api directory, but I haven't examined each of the 20K+ files.

Comment: `curl` would be additionally interesting but not really the point I would like to learn

Comment: re-formulated problem as it was not really clear where the wrong linking exactly happens, e.g. from tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html to Runnable

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have found a bug in `wget`. I tried several iterations of `wget` commands trying nail down the why. My first thought was that the regex was making `wget` treat it as two disjointed sets, and not linking between them. I worked out a non-regex version to get, seemingly, the same files, converting the options to long form and making them discrete (--mirror is compound) and adding in a log file and keeping the originals:

```
wget --recursive --convert-links --backup-converted --page-requisites --no-host-directories --level=inf --adjust-extension --include /javase/tutorial,/javase/tutorialJWS,/javase/8/docs/api https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/index.html 2>&1 | tee wget.log
```

Grepping the files for comparison I found the it appears every link *not* converted was an absolute link in the original source. All the originally relative links were kept relative (not really converted). The output from `wget` claims to have 'converted' the files in question, but only non-anchor tags seem to have been touched.

I used the same options, and equivalent `--include` parameters on a site I control, after setting some links to absolute, including images. And got the same results: only non-anchor tags with absolute addresses were converted, absolute anchors were not affected.

For the size of your project, the prospect of converting the links to relative seems daunting, even with a script. I came across a PerlMonk post [Change Absolute to Relative links in HTML files](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=56338) with a perl script that is aimed at the problem you now face.

I haven't tested it, but it has an option for making backup copies as a safety net, so it could be worth a try.

Meantime, I guess you get the privilege of reporting a bug on `wget`. Just for reference my version is:

```
$ wget --version
GNU Wget 1.14 built on linux-gnu.

+digest +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file +nls +ntlm +opie +ssl/openssl 

Wgetrc: 
    /etc/wgetrc (system)
Locale: /usr/share/locale 
Compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/etc/wgetrc" 
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/share/locale" -I. -I../lib -I../lib 
    -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall 
    -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables 
    -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g 
Link: gcc -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall 
    -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables 
    -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -lproxy /usr/lib64/libssl.so 
    /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so /usr/lib64/libz.so -ldl -lz -lz -lidn 
    ftp-opie.o openssl.o http-ntlm.o ../lib/libgnu.a
```